# How do I make sure I can keep ingestion client running if I have heavy read operations on a table?

Tags: postgresql, questdb

I am using influx line to insert records into a table in Questdb at a constant and high rate. I have multiple postgres clients attached performing read operations, some are Grafana dashboards which do some heavy aggregations across the table. It looks like when I refresh the dashboards, I'm hitting some issues:

```
... t.LineTcpConnectionContext [31] queue full, consider increasing queue size or number of writer jobs
```

Is there a way to make sure I don't kick the kick the insert client out or increase the queue like mentioned in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one client writing Influx line protocol over TCP, it's possible to have a dedicated worker thread for this purpose. The config key that you can set this with is `line.tcp.worker.count` and this should be set in a [configuration file](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration) or via environment variable. Setting one dedicated thread in `server.conf`  would look like the following:

```
line.tcp.worker.count=1
```